# Identifier 'length' is not defined. 'null' does not contain such a member ng(0)

Tags: angular

Error:- `Identifier 'length' is not defined. 'null' does not contain such a member ng(0).`

Below using, keyvalue which is inbuilt pipe of angular(ie it Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.)

## .html

```
<div *ngIf="(widget?.response | keyvalue)?.length"></div>
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code. We have no idea what widget or keyvalue look like

Comment: Keyvalue is inbuilt pipe of angular.

Comment: Can you reproduce in stackblitz?

Comment: @Manzer if widget.response is a Map instance, wouldn't you need to call .size rather than .length? If you're just trying to iterate through an object's properties, disregard this :)

Answer (score 0):

You are better of handling the comparison login in the component instead of the template. Also consider that `keyvalue` is an impure pipe. It might be called too many times than your actual requirement. Something like this should do it

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private isWidgetValid = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private setWidgetValidity() {
    if (this.widget) {
      this.isWidgetValid = (Object.entries(this.widget.response)).length ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="isWidgetValid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use the pipeline keyvalue if you just want to check if your dictionary has values?

If you want to iterate over your dictionary and check if it has values use the code below.

```
<div *ngFor="let res of widget?.response| keyvalue;">
  <app-response[res]="res.value"></app-reponse>
</div>
```

If you just want to check if it has values use the awnser of Michael D